# VBA - Subscript out of range error

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, copy-paste

I am trying to write a macro to do the following:

1. Prompt user to open their file, then add new "Mismatch" sheet to the
   file
2. Find the column name of "Cust Bill To ID" & "SAP CMF#", and store
   the data below these two columns to 2 different arrays[BTID() &
   CMF()].
3. If BTID(i) is not equal to CMF(i), copy entire row and paste it to
   Mismatch sheet.

But the arrays having the subscription out of range error and the Mismatch sheet only have the column name duplicate from the original sheet (the data are missing).

Result:
 [image]

Code:

```
Sub Mismatch()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim authSht As Worksheet ' Renamed this variable
Dim misSht As Worksheet ' Added a worksheet variable
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim last As Integer
Dim BTID() As String
Dim CMF() As String
Dim rng1 As Range ' Added this variable
Dim rng2 As Range ' Added this variable


''OPEN FILE
sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xla;*.xlam, All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select Authorization Issued Report File")
If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set auth = Workbooks.Open(sFileName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)

'add new sheet
Set sht = Sheets.Add
sht.Name = "Mismatch"

Sheets("Mismatch").Select
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mismatch").Tab
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With


Set authSht = Worksheets("Authorizations Issued")
Set misSht = Worksheets("Mismatch")


''find Mismatch
authSht.Range("A2:BT2").Copy Destination:=misSht.Range("A1")

    last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'col = ActiveSheet.End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng1 = authSht.Range("A2:BH2")
    Set rng2 = rng1


    For Each c In rng1.Cells
        If c.Value = "Cust Bill To ID" Then Set rng1 = c
    Next c
    For Each c In rng2.Cells
        If c.Value = "SAP CMF#" Then Set rng2 = c
    Next c

    Dim l As Integer
    l = 2
    ReDim BTID(2 To l)
    ReDim CMF(2 To l)

    For i = 2 To last
        BTID(i) = rng1.Offset(i, 0).Value
        CMF(i) = rng2.Offset(i, 0).Value
        If i < last Then
            ReDim Preserve BTID(1 To i + 1)
            ReDim Preserve CMF(1 To i + 1)
        End If
    Next

    For k = 2 To last
        If BTID(k) = CMF(k) Then
            authSht.Range("A" & k & ":BH" & k).Copy Destination:=misSht.Range("A" & l)
            l = l + 1

        Else: l = l

        End If
    Next


misSht.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit



End Sub
```

And I realized that the code below doesn't work in the for loop.

```
 authSht.Range("A" & k & ":BH" & k).Copy Destination:=misSht.Range("A" & l)
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Instead of Sheets("Mismatch").Select try to use Activate, Sheets("Mismatch").activate

Comment: also, try using `match` to find them, `rng1=authsheet.range("a1").offset(0,application.worksheetfunction.match(....`

Comment: @PareshJ The result is same with this change.

Comment: When you are opening a workbook from another workbook, it's always a good practice do declare two Workbook variables and set one to ThisWorkbook and another to the workbook which is being opened by the code. Later you can qualify all the sheet variables with their workbook variables. And when you add the sheet, qualify the Sheets.Add with the workbook reference also, that way you are sure that which workbook will contain the added sheet.

Comment: @sktneer, what's wrong with just using `ThisWorkbook`? I don't see the point of creating another variable, unless you find that "ThisWorkbook" isn't descriptive enough

Comment: Nothing wrong using ThisWorkbook alone. But somehow the sheet variables when being set first time should be qualified with the workbook they belong to.

Comment: @sktneer my raw data (Authorization Issued) is actually on the same work book with "Mismatch" sheet.

Comment: Subscript out of range error normally occurs when the object you are using doesn't exists. That's why I was suggesting to declare two workbook variables and while setting the sheet variables first time, qualify them with the workbook variable also. So later there won't be any conflict in the code even if the two worksheets with the same names available in two workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite convinced your issue is about not fully qualifying range references and rely on implicit `ActiveSheet` (and `ActiveWorkbook`)

your last sheet selection is

```
Sheets("Mismatch").Select
```

which activates a brand new sheet with only headers placed in row 1, and then you run

```
last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

thus setting `last` to `1`, so that your subsequent `For i = 2 To last` loops all don't run a single statement, leaving you with empty hands (well, cells) in `Mismatch` sheet

the most straight repair of such a situation would be placing:

```
authSht.Activate
```

right before:

```
last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

but the *real* patch would be using fully qualified range references, like follows:

substitute:

```
''find Mismatch
authSht.Range("A2:BT2").Copy Destination:=misSht.Range("A1")

    last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'col = ActiveSheet.End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng1 = authSht.Range("A2:BH2")
    Set rng2 = rng1
```

with the following code:

```
With authSht
''find Mismatch
    .Range("A2:BT2").Copy Destination:=misSht.Range("A1")

    last = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'col = ActiveSheet.End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng1 = .Range("A2:BH2")
End With
Set rng2 = rng1 '<--| what0s this for? you can stick to 'rng1'
```

Comment: Thank you! But after I've done the substitution, the subscription out of range error went to this line. `ReDim Preserve BTID(1 To i + 1)`  Why?